# Is this termite or moisture damage?

Tags: termite

Anybody can tell if this is termite or water damage on the picture?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is both, termites are attracted to damp wood. Carpenter ants will do the same.

Comment: I was thinking the same, if there are no active ants termites in the area it may be an old nest that was poisoned.